# Java appending to an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have 2 files with a list of entries, first file has 5 item and separate by ';;', second file only has 1 entry.(note* both files have equal number of lines.) I want to combine both file together into a single arraylist and re-write them to a new file. How should I do it?

### first file

```
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] items = line.split(";;");

        list.add(items[1]+";;" + items[2] + ";;" + items[3] + ";;" + items[4] + ";;" + items[5]);

    }
```

### second file

```
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {



        list2.add(line);


    }
```

### file1

```
null;;13;;male;;USA;;single;;address
null;;12;;female;;USA;;single;;address
```

### file 2

```
jack
mary
```

### output

```
jack;;13;;male;;USA;;single;;address
```

Comment: You can add an example of the files content to make it more easy.

Comment: Confirmation: do you really need to combine both `ArrayList` into a single-combined `ArrayList` before writing it to a new file?

Comment: you don't want items[0]?

Comment: ya i dunt wan item0 in first file, but it will be replace by the entry in the 2nd file

Answer (score 1):

Use two `bufferedeader` for two files

```
while ((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null && (line2=br2.readLine())!=null) {
        String[] items = line1.split(";;");
        String firstName=line2;
        list.add(firstName+";;"+items[1]+";;" + items[2] + ";;" + items[3] + ";;" + items[4] + ";;" + items[5]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need your `List` to contain `;;`-separated items from the first list + `;;` and the item from the same row from the second list, here is the solution:

```
String lineFromFirst, lineFromSecond;
while ((lineFromFirst = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] items = lineFromFirst .split(";;");

    lineFromSecond = brForSecondFile.readLine();
    //I assume no checks are neccesary as you wrote that the files has equal number of lines

   list.add(lineFromSecond + ";;" + items[1]+";;" + items[2] + ";;" + items[3] + ";;" + items[4] + ";;" + items[5]);
}
```

Comment: forgot to note that, the 2nd file need to be at item[0], which mean the first entry

Comment: @newbieprogrammer Code you posted in the answer actually ignores the first column of the first file - you do not use `item[0]`. Is that intended behavior? Although I updated the answer to add item from the second file before the items from the second (starting from second column of the first file).

Comment: yup i didnt want the null which is item[0]

Comment: @newbieprogrammer Then I think you can use my code.